# how to play audio from server while the audio stored mysql database via ajax post jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.play_btn").each(function(){
    var btn_id = $(this);
     btn_id.click(function(){           
            var audio_id =      btn_id.parent("div.ply_btn_container").siblings("span.idmusic_only").text();

 btn_id.attr("src", "http://localhost/Forepost/icons  /pause_btn.png").removeClass("play_btn").addClass("pause_btn");
         // ajax call

               $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/Forepost/php/audio_id.php',
            data:{audio_id:audio_id},
            dataType:'text',
            success:function(resultData){
                var mp3_name = resultData;

                audio_player();


                },
            error:function(){
                alert("oops something went wrong");
            // oops something went wrong
        }
        });
         // end of ajax call
         // function audio player
        function audio_player(){
            var src_audio = "http://localhost/Forepost/audios/"+mp3_name;

                var audio_music = new Audio();
                audio_music.setAttribute("src", src_audio);


                audio_music.trigger('play');
         }

         // function audio player
    });
});
```

});

so far the ajax call is fine. but the problem is playing the audio.
  i have several play buttons and upon click any of them , i do the ajax call  to fetch the relevant audio from server through mysql database.Any help will  be of graet  value to me , since i have tried this for nights. Thank you in   advance.

Comment: I have never done something like that before... but if I had to guess I would say you might need to find a way to add it inline in the same way you would add an image inline, but with audio. So you would start with the mime type and then add the data in some form like base64 or something... maybe the html5 audio tags might help you out there. Or you might have to generate the file with the serverside code and send back the link. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: sorry .. you can use audio_music.play(); instead of audio_music.trigger('play');

Comment: thank you i can try that .and is there a better way to it,rather than using ajax